# Unknown system variable 'ANSI_NULLS'

Tags: mysql

I want to connect the MySQL database to Assure Id 2009 Software.When I import the SQL file it gives me error like:

Unknown system variable 'ANSI_NULLS'

My Sql is like:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [ActivityLog](
    [ActivityLogID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TemplateName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TableName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RecordID] [bigint] NULL,
    [KeyName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [KeyValue] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ActivityDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ActivityBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ActivityCode] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ActivityLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ActivityLogID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Please help?

Comment: Search for `ANSI_NULLS` in the SQL File and include the appropriate code in your question.

Comment: Looks like you must be running the wrong script. Presumably there is a MySQL version http://www.safecardid.com/blog/asure-id-2009-setting-up-a-mysql-as-the-native-database/

Comment: which one is the right script for mysql?

Answer (score 2):

This often occurs when a script from MSSQLServer is brought over to Mysql and run, during migration or testing a random script.

Mysql has no such variable and ansi_nulls `concept` is on be default.

from 50k feet, if you are happy with NULL + thing = NULL then rem the offending lines out and continue.

```
set  @var1=NULL;
set @var2="kittens";
select @var1+@var2;
-- null
```

**Edit:**

By the way, you just edited your question and showed us Microsoft Sql Server syntax.

Perhaps wherever you got that from has a mysql variant so you don't need to convert it by hand.